# Unity2D Attack Animation and Damage Timing

Tags: unity-game-engine

Context:

I have a 2D game where you spawn units that move right and attack enemies until you destroy the enemy base. Each unit is instantiated and has the raycast2D component. When it detects nothing it walks, when it detects an enemy it stops and attacks with an attack cooldown.

Right now, as soon as it detects an enemy, it plays the attack animation and deals damage at the same time. For example: if the attack animation takes 0.5 seconds and the cooldown is 1 second, the timers run at the same time and the animation doesn't match the damage tick.

The raycast code stops moving, turns off walk animation and checks if it can attack.

```
else if (hitInfo.collider.gameObject.tag == "Enemy")
        {

            transform.Translate(Vector2.right * 0 * Time.deltaTime);
            anim.SetBool("isWalking", false);

            if (attackCurrentTime < attackCD)
            {
                attackCurrentTime += Time.deltaTime;
            }
            else
            {
                attackCurrentTime = 0;
                basicAttackEnemy();

            }
        }
```

this is the basicAttackEnemy(); function. it just starts the animation and deals damage

```
void basicAttackEnemy()
        {
            anim.SetTrigger("attackEnemy");
            hitInfo.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<EnemyIA>().TakeDamage(attackDamage);

        }
```

How would I change my code or do something else within Unity to let my damage tick, animation and cooldown timer sync up correctly?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: The problem lies in the Timings of Animations, I guess. Can you share your animation states and transitions with us?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have some kind of creature doing the animation, and they have some kind of weapon (even if the weapon is just a fist, or claw) what I've found is the "best" way to implement attacks, and damage, is to use the onCollision methods to tell when you've made contact with the enemy.

What you do is the following,

Step 1: Create an additional collider on the weapon, or part of their body that should come close enough to the enemy that's supposed to take the damage.  Feel free to make this collider fairly large, as it's not going to really "show" anything during play.

Step 2: Create a new variable in your code [SerializeField] private BoxCollider weaponCollider.  (You can chane this from BoxCollider if you need a different shape, no issue).

Step 3: Save those changes to your code, and now in the editor, you'll see that on the GameObject that has the script for that attack animation (player object?) it will have an empty slot for a parameter, drag and drop the new collider from the inspector into that slot, this will tell your code which collider you're talking about.

Step 4: You'll need to use layers to identify the enemies, but don't worry too much about that.  This tutorial should get you most of what you need -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=65S5Hncw6yM

Step 5: Finally you can update your code to something like the following.  (It may not be exact, but it should get you close enough that you can bring yourself the rest of the way.

```
void basicAttackEnemy()
        {
            anim.SetTrigger("attackEnemy");
            weaponCollider.enabled = true;
        }
```

And Step 7: Create a new script with the following, and attach it on the collider.

```
void onCollisionEnter(Collision collision) {
  if (gameObject.Layer == "Enemy") {
    hitInfo.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<EnemyIA>().TakeDamage(attackDamage);
    self.enabled = false;
  }
}
```

You may need to change the OnCollisionEnter script some, and for more information about colliders, and collisions, try this tutorial, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZoZcBgRR9ns

But in general, what all of this together is this.  It creates a system, where your attack animation activates a collider which checks to see if it actually hit the enemy, if it hits, then it does damage to that enemy, and turns itself off again.  It turns itself off so you don't end up one-hit-killing everything, as otherwise, it'd do damage dozens of times in a second during the attack animation.